# Simplifying the Creation of Commented Ordered and Unordered Lists in LaTeX

Tags: macros, enumerate, tabularx, itemize, booktabs

I am currently trying to simplify the process of creating commented ordered and unordered lists in LaTeX. I have a method that achieves the desired visual result, but the syntax seems overly complex. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner or more straightforward approach.

Here's my current implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{Example A}

\hspace{\parindent} \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\hspace{0.5cm}}lX}
    \textbullet & First Statement  & \# First Comment  \\ \addlinespace
    \textbullet & Second Statement & \# Second Comment \\ \addlinespace
    \textbullet & Third Statement  & \# Third Comment  \\ \addlinespace
\end{tabularx} \hspace{-\parindent}

This is some commentary on the list.

\section{Example B}

\hspace{\parindent} \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\hspace{0.5cm}}lX}
    1. & First Statement  & \# First Comment  \\ \addlinespace
    2. & Second Statement & \# Second Comment \\ \addlinespace
    3. & Third Statement  & \# Third Comment  \\ \addlinespace
\end{tabularx} \hspace{-\parindent}

This is some commentary on the list.

\end{document}
```

I attempted to simplify this by creating new commands for the beginning and end of the list, but encountered issues with closing the list:

```
\newcommand{\beginCommentList}{
    \hspace{\parindent} \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\hspace{0.5cm}}lX}}
    
\newcommand{\closeCommentList}{
    \end{tabularx} \hspace{-\parindent}}
```

Ideally, I'd like to find a solution that allows for a simpler syntax, such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Define CommentItemize
% Define CommentEnumerate

\begin{document}

\section{Example A}

\begin{CommentItemize}
    First Statement  & First Comment
    Second Statement & Second Comment
    Third Statement  & Third Comment
\end{CommentItemize}

This is some commentary on the list.

\section{Example B}

\begin{CommentEnumerate}
    First Statement  & First Comment
    Second Statement & Second Comment
    Third Statement  & Third Comment
\end{CommentEnumerate}

This is some commentary on the list.

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions or feedback on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `\hspace{\parindent} \noindent` is this intended? the `\noindent` does nothing here so this forces an indent of  2 \parindent + 1 word space.

Comment: "but encountered issues with closing the list:" see the tabularx manual, you need `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx` not `\begin{tabularx}`  (and `\newenvironment`)

Answer (score 1):

Coerce a list in a table column could be a bad idea. You can use the normal itemize or enumerate environments but instead of the standard `\item Statement` use a macro as `\foo{Statement}{Comment}`. The advantage is that  in the same list you can still use just `\item Statement` when the comment is not needed at all in some row, or type some like `\foo[30]{Statement}{Comment}`if you want limit some item to only the 30% of the width to include a very long comment without affect to the whole list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\newcommand\foo[3][5]{\item\parbox[t]{.#1\linewidth}{#2}\hfill\parbox[t]{\dimexpr.95\linewidth-0.#1\linewidth}{\color{olive}\sffamily {\bfseries\#} #3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\foo {First Statement} {First Comment}  

\foo {Second Statement} {Second Comment}  

\foo {Third Statement} {Third Comment}  

\foo {\lipsum[1][1-2]} {\lipsum[2][1]}  

\foo {\lipsum[6][1-2]} {\lipsum[7][1]}  

\foo[20] {\lipsum[1][1]} {\lipsum[2][1-3]}   

\foo[70] {\lipsum[1][1-6]} {\lipsum[2][1]}  

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```